# indexedDB doesn't store anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

IndexedDB doesn't work for me, I've have tried in Firefox, Chrome, Edge with tons of examples from GitHub, from Google searches and I've made 3-4 different experiments guided by MDN Docs, but without success.

I have tried: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) - [idb lib](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) - [google idb](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb) - [github simple example](https://gist.github.com/greenido/3769507) - [tuts+](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-indexeddb--net-34673)

Everytime when 'add', 'put', open database, set transaction the console.log result me 'success' / 'Did it', etc -- but the 'Developer Tools' (at IndexedDB section) is always empty and doesn't show any record, only 'Database' name, 'dbVersion' and 'objectStore' name without any record. I also can not get that 'succesfully' inserted records.

I really don't know what can I do in this case, that's why I ask for help.

OS Windows 8.1

Google Chrome   63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Firefox Version 57.0.4

JavaScript  V8 6.3.292.49

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/cLscs8h1/
[image]

Comment: Provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/cLscs8h1/